# Pandas groupby compare count equal values in 2 columns in excel with subrows

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have an excel file like this:

[image]

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-yqkkQYNUorTcW1zjMz3nx_D_itCsMk/view?usp=sharing)

```
.----.-------------.-------------------------.-----------------.
|    |     ID      | Shareholder - Last name |   DM Cognome    |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
| 1. | 01287560153 | MASSIRONI               | Bocapine Ardaya |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
|    |             | CAGNACCI                |                 |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
| 2. | 05562881002 |                         | Directors       |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
| 3. | 04113870655 | SABATO                  | Sabato          |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
|    |             | VILLARI                 |                 |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
| 4. | 01419190846 | SALMERI                 | Salmeri         |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
|    |             | MICALIZZI               | Lipari          |
:----+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------:
|    |             | LIPARI                  |                 |
'----'-------------'-------------------------'-----------------'
```

I open this file with pandas and `ffill` the ID column since there are subrows. Then `groupby` by ID to get the count of any equal values on the `Shareholder - Last name` and `DM\nCognome` columns. However I can't. In this case the result should be `0 row1 0 row2 1 row3 2 row4`.

> It should be noted that row 4 is consist of 3 subrow and row3 also consist of 2 subrow.(ex)

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the best way to read an unorganised excel file like above and do lots of comparisons, replacing values etc.
2. How can I achieve the results that I mentioned earlier.

Here is what I did, but it doesn't work:

```
data['ID'] = data['ID'].fillna(method='ffill')
data.groupby('ID', sort=False, as_index=False)['Shareholder - Last name', 'DM\nCognome'].apply(lambda x: (x['Shareholder - Last name']==x['DM\nCognome']).count())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read as input the table (keeping the ID as string instead of float):

```
df = pd.read_excel("Workbook1.xlsx", converters={'ID':str})
df = df.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1) #drop this column since it is not useful
```

Fill the ID and if a shareholder is missing replace Nan with "Missing":

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(method='ffill')
df["Shareholder - Last name"] = df["Shareholder - Last name"].fillna("missing")
```

Convert to lowercase the surnames:

```
df["Shareholder - Last name"] = df["Shareholder - Last name"].str.lower()
```

Custom function to count how many householders occur in the other column:

```
def f(group):
    s = pd.Series(group["DM\nCognome"].str.lower())
    count = 0
    for surname in group["Shareholder - Last name"]:
        count += s.str.count(surname).sum()
    return count
```

And finally get the count for each ID:

```
df.groupby("ID",sort=False)[["Shareholder - Last name", "DM\nCognome"]].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Output:

```
ID
01287560153    0.0
05562881002    0.0
04113870655    1.0
01419190846    2.0
```